# Phonegap for Android + JQuery

Tags: android, jquery, phonegap-plugins

I'm working on an Android App that is ported to an app using phonegap.

It's coded in HTML, CSS, Javascript/JQuery.

There is a button a user can click. If a user taps the button it should change the buttons text color to black, when the user removes his finger from the screen the button text should turn white.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, your HTML will be like this:

```
 <a class="ui-btn ui-btn-b btn ui-btn-inline">button</a>
```

And then your CSS:

```
.btn{ color:#fff !important;}

.btn:active{ color:#000 !important;}
```

A working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fwn529sp/4/)